# JavaScript date to firestore timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a form with datepicker which stores the date like "1559389274032".

Is there a way to convert this to a firestore timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var myDate = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
```

Where new Date() would be your timestamp constructor.

Also I'm 99% sure that you dont even need it, this should save the value as a date, just make sure you dont convert it to a string on your end.

```
ref.update({ created_at: new Date() })
```

Comment: You're right, adding as a JavaScript date simply works!

Answer (score 0):

To know about the firestore timestamp format :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#constructor

If you have imported firebase sdk..... then you can try this:

```
let d=new Date(milliseconds) //pass in your milliseconds, this will return the js date object
let timestamp=firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(d)
```

Comment: That's because there should not be `new` in front of `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(d)`.